MySQL Master Slave substitution problem in Node.js
I'm trying to configure master slave in nodejs web. I want to connect to the slave server when the master one is collapsed. I tried to stop the master and  it really connected to the slave. However, when I signed in on the web, the web crashed. How should I fix this?
Here is the code
let db = null;

function createDatabaseConnection() {
  if (!db) {
    db = mysql.createConnection(master);

    db.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('Cant connect to master server:', err);
      console.log('Change to slave server.');
      db = mysql.createConnection(slave);
      reconnect(db);
    });
  }

  return db;
}

function reconnect(connection) {
  connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Cant connect to slave server:', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Connected to slave server.');
    }
  });

  connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('Cant connect to slave server:', err);
  });
}

module.exports = createDatabaseConnection();

Here is the error
Cant connect to master server: AggregateError
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
    at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5) {
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  fatal: true,
  [errors]: [
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1634:14)
        at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1664:40) {
      errno: -4078,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '::1',
      port: 3306
    },
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1634:14)
        at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1664:40) {
      errno: -4078,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 3306
    }
  ]
}
Change to slave server.
Connected to slave server.
[]
C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\HotelBooking\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:164
    const err = new Error(
                ^

Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state


The error handler runs asynchronously. It has no effect on the value of db returned by createDatabaseConnection(), which is always the master connection.

Look into something like haproxy, which can automatically detect a server failure and connect to the working server.

This file exports the value of db, but only the first value of db. Rewriting this to use the promise-based API that mysql2 provides will make it a lot simpler potentially to solve this.
